# MediaKit reports not enough space on device for requested operation

Tags: hard-drive, time-machine, disk-utility, partition

I am running macOS 10.13.3 High Sierra and I have a 4TB WD external hard disk that is partitioned as follows:

```
/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *4.0 TB     disk2
   1:         Microsoft Reserved                         134.2 MB   disk2s1
   2:       Microsoft Basic Data NTFS                    3.2 TB     disk2s2
   3:       Microsoft Basic Data exFAT                   506.0 GB   disk2s3
   4:                  Apple_HFS TIMEMACHINE             272.9 GB   disk2s4
```

Time Machine app recognizes the disk and all the partitions but when it attempts to erase the partition a popup message appears saying "MediaKit reports not enough space on device for requested operation"

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that Disk Utility isn't able to reformat your drive from NTFS to APFS. You can format it to HFS+, then Disk Utility will pick up and do the rest for you. Here is a tutorial with detailed, [step by step instructions](https://mycyberuniverse.com/web/how-fix-mediakit-reports-not-enough-space-on-device.html).

Note that this will erase your entire disk (in case you have multiple volumes).

Summary of commands needed, in terminal:

```
diskutil list
diskutil unmountDisk force disk2
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/rdisk2 bs=1024 count=1024
diskutil partitionDisk disk2 GPT JHFS+ "New Drive Name" 0g
```

Where disk2 is the name of your external drive, listed from `diskutil list`

Comment: Not sure, but isn't using `R` instead of `0g` the right way?

Comment: @ÖmerRıfatKuldaşlı I think R and 0g will both fill the remaining space available. 0g worked fine for me!

Comment: Note that this will erase your entire disk.

Comment: the last commands says Error: -69825: Wiping volume data to prevent future accidental probing failed

Answer (score 3):

Whilst nuking the drive (using `dd`) will work, it is the nuclear option that doesn't address the problem. The issue is that apparently you need an EFI partition of at least 200MB. An EFI partition is just a regular FAT32 partition with the `boot` flag set, so you might have to use `GParted` on a Linux recovery disk to arrange it (I'm sure its possible on the Mac, but I have no idea).

Answer (score 2):

As noted [here](https://priyanksharma.com/tech/mediakit-reports-not-enough-space-on-device-for-requested-operation/), one possible cause for this error is if the drive does not have a large enough EFI partition.

I did not want to wipe my entire drive, only one partition, but I could afford to backup the contents of the first partition. My process was to backup the first partition (from Windows), delete the first partition (from Windows), reformat the last partition of the drive (from Mac) which created an EFI partition, add back the first partition (from Windows), then restore the first partition from the backup. Any other OS could be used instead of Windows, and you could also use `gdisk` from Homebrew to delete the first partition from within Mac.

Hope this helps anyone who does not want to erase their entire drive.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with MediaKit reporting ‘not enough space on device.’

I used a Windows 10 installation USB flash drive to boot my MacBook Pro.

If you follow the installation process, there is a point where it ask you to create a clean install. Choose the clean install option. After that you can select drives or partitions to install Windows. At this point you can delete all partitions on the drive.

That is what I did. I deleted all partitions and did not make a new one. After this I cancelled Windows installation and reboot MacBook Pro with macOS install USB flash drive. Then I could format SSD without problems to MacOS extended journaled with GUID.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create an EFI system partition follow my commands in diskpart (in Windows 11, you can use parallels on Mac)

- list disk
- select disk 1
- list partition
- select partition 1
- shrink partition 1 desired = 500
- create partition efi size = 500

1 can be replaced with the desired number and That's it this will get rid of the error.