# Want to upgrade to Mac OS High Sierra and it shows MediaKit reports not enough space on device for requested operation

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, high-sierra

Trying to update my MacBook from os El Capitan to High Sierra  on reboot it shows **MediaKit reports not enough space on device for requested operation**

Answer (score 1):

Typically this means you need to erase your drive. It could be a permanent storage error, but most of the time you can fix things by erasing the entire drive and reinstalling.

- [MediaKit reports not enough space on device for requested operation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/317048/mediakit-reports-not-enough-space-on-device-for-requested-operation)
- [Unable to format Mac internal drive (disk0)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/327532/unable-to-format-mac-internal-drive-disk0)

Do you need time to back up or instructions to erase and install macOS?

Comment: I need instructions on how to erase and install macOS High Sierra

Comment: @Emmanuel https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372. Once you boot the installer from your USB drive, go into Disk Utility and erase the disk before installing.